# I want to have my React application access my Google Cloud Storage to display the image in my app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a MERN app where I am adding products as part of the products I upload and image to Google Cloud Storage and I get the URL back as a response.

I then send the URL to the front end where I want to display the image as well as save it in the database with the rest of the information about the product.

My issue is:

when I put the URL in an `img` tag and and try to access it I get the access error. I am trying to figure out what it the best way to access the images but I don't want to make them public. I have seen many answers but they seem to require you to make the bucket public. I tried adding my local host under the permissions but that did not work.

```
function AddProduct() {

    const [category, setCategory] = useState("")

    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [price, setPrice] = useState({})

    const [cPrice, setCPrice] = useState("")

    const [concentPrice, setConcentPrice] = useState({})

    const [preRollPrice, setPreRollPrice] = useState({})

    const [uploadedImage, setUploadedImage] = useState("")
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("")

    const [image, setImage] = useState("")




    const addProducts = async () => {

        const res = axios.post("/api/v1/products/addProducts", {})

    }


    const uploadHandler = async () => {
        let formData = new FormData()
        console.log(uploadedImage)
        formData.append("file", uploadedImage[0])
        formData.append('folder', 'products')
        console.log(formData.folder)
        const res = await axios.post("/api/v1/upload", formData, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/formdata"
            }


        })
        if (res.data.message) {
            setMessage(res.data.message)
            setImage(res.data.image)
        }
        else {
            setMessage(res.data)

        }
        console.log(res)

    }




    return (
        <div>
            <div className='addProdFormWrapper'>
                <Form>
                    <h1>Add New Product</h1>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                        <Form.Label>Product Name</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter product name" />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group controlId="formFile" className="mb-4">
                        <Form.Label>Add image of product</Form.Label>
                        <div className='imageMessage'>{message}</div>
                        <div className="uploadedImageDiv"><img className="uploadedImage" src={image} /></div>
                        <Form.Control type="file" onChange={(e) => setUploadedImage(e.target.files)} />
                    </Form.Group>
                    {uploadedImage !== "" && image === "" ?
                        <Form.Group controlId="formFile" className="mb-4">
                            <Button variant="primary" type="button" onClick={uploadHandler}>
                                upload
                            </Button>
                        </Form.Group>
                        : null

                    }

                    <Form.Select className='mb-3' aria-label="Select A Catagory" onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}>
                        <option>Select a category</option>
                        <option value="flower"> Flower</option>
                        <option value="CBD">CBD</option>
                        <option value="cartridges">Cartridges</option>
                        <option value="concentrates"> Concentrates</option>
                        <option value="Pre-roll">Pre-Rolls</option>
                        <option value="topicals">Topicals</option>
                        <option value="other">Other</option>
                    </Form.Select>


                    {category === "flower" ?
                        <Price price={price} setPrice={setPrice} />
                        : category === "concentrates" ?
                            <ConcentPrice concentPrice={concentPrice} setConcentPrice={setConcentPrice} />
                            : category === "Pre-roll" ?
                                <PreeRoll preRollPrice={preRollPrice} setPreRollPrice={setPreRollPrice} />
                                : category === "cartridges" ?

                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicCart">
                                        <Form.Label>Price </Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control type="number" name="cartridge" placeholder="enter price" onChange={(e) => setCPrice(e.target.value)} />
                                    </Form.Group>

                                    : null
                    }



                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: By frontend, do you mean code that runs in the client's web browser? You can either make the storage object public, use a Signed URL, or download the object to your server and serve it from there. Don't use the third option.

Comment: @jaydanasara, does the comment above answer your question?

Comment: I don't want to make public. From the documentation it appears that a signed URL is temporary. Is there no permanent way as my app would continuously need access.

Comment: Where does the code run that needs access? In the client's browser or the backend server? The only permanent access method is **public**.

Comment: the code that needs access is front end

Comment: Yes the client browser

Comment: For permanent access in a client browser, the only permanent solution is public.